# Writing a batch script/file for converting a between two folders/files structure

Tags: batch-file, directory-structure

I'm very bad with batch files/scripts, especially compared to ones who are "fluent" with it :). I would really like help with creating a simple (and easy to "adjust") batch file/script which could help me do what i need to do (described below).

I am trying to convert the directory structure of my photos' directories. I have most of these directories arranged in one/similar way and i would like to convert it to a different structure which will be more convenient for me.

***My current structure is a follows -***

```
PhotosCollection01\
|-> Img003.jpg
|-> Img004.jpg
|-> Img005.jpg
|-> Img007.jpg
|-> Img010.jpg
|-> ...
|-> Chosen\
    |-> Img005.jpg
    |-> Img010.jpg
```

***The batch file/script should change the structure to this -***

```
PhotosCollection01\
|-> NewName001.jpg (formerly Img003.jpg)
|-> NewName002.jpg (formerly Img004.jpg)
|-> NewName004.jpg (formerly Img007.jpg)
|-> ...
|-> Chosen\
    |-> NewName003.jpg (formerly Img005.jpg)
    |-> NewName005.jpg (formerly Img010.jpg)
```

***This is what the batch file/script did -***

```
1) Names are all "NewName???.jpg" (from 001 and up)
2) No duplication of photos under the "Photos" directory and its sub-dirs
3) The "Chosen" directory holds the same amount of photos as before (these were removed from the "Photos" directory)
4) The numbering order of the "NewName" photos is kept in the same order as the "Img" order (although numbering is reset to start from 000)
5) I would love to be able to have "PhotosCollectionXX", "NewNameXXX" and "Chosen" to be able to consist of spaces in their real names
```

Until (if) i get an answer, I will try to learn and write the script myself. Any help would be very appreciated!

Many thanks in advance,
Eyal

Comment: I don't believe, there's any sane method to achieve 4) using batch files. For that you need some real programming language. If you want to stay close to scripting, consider PowerShell or VBScript/JScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "relroot=u:\photos collection 01"
SET "oldmask=im age"
SET "newmask=new name"
SET "ext=jpg"
SET "skipped="
::
:: step 1 - ensure no 'newname*.ext' exists in the subtree
::
FOR /f %%i IN (
  'DIR /s/b/a-d "%relroot%\%newmask%*.%ext%" 2^>nul^|FIND /c /v "" '
 ) DO IF NOT %%i==0 ECHO Files matching new mask already exist&GOTO :EOF 
::
:: step 2 - list target files
::
:temploop
SET tempfile=%temp%\Photo%random%
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" GOTO temploop
:: now have random tempfile name
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (
  'DIR /s/b/a-d "%relroot%\%oldmask%*.%ext%" '
  ) DO (
  ECHO %%~ni*%%~fi
)
)>"%tempfile%1"
::
:: Now do the rename
::
SET count=1000
SET prev=%newmask%
FOR /f %%i IN ('find /c "*" ^<"%tempfile%1"') DO IF %%i gtr 1000 ECHO %%i files - exceeds capacity&GOTO :eof
FOR /f "delims=*" %%i IN ('SORT "%tempfile%1"') DO (CALL :incren "%%i")
IF DEFINED skipped ECHO some files were NOT renamed&DIR /s/b/a-d "%relroot%\%oldmask%*.%ext%"

DEL "%tempfile%1"
GOTO :eof

:incren
:: repeat?
IF "%prev%"==%1 GOTO :EOF
:: no - process next name found
SET "prev=%~1"
FOR %%n IN (firstname secondname) DO (SET %%n=)
:: scan the tempfile, looking for matches to name found
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=*" %%m IN ("%tempfile%1") DO IF /i "%%m"=="%prev%" (
 IF DEFINED firstname SET skipped=Y&IF NOT DEFINED secondname SET secondname=%%n
 IF NOT DEFINED firstname SET firstname=%%n
)
IF DEFINED secondname SET firstname=%secondname%
ECHO REN "%firstname%" "%newmask%%count:~-3%.%ext%"
SET /a count+=1
GOTO :eof
```

Well, not too hard after all.

Not quite gone along with your spec - I eschew deleting files, so I mereley didn't rename any targets with duplicated names.

WAY too much attention is paid to trying to process silly filenames IMO. If you use characters like `!%^)=` in your filenames - well - you so smart - you figger it out.

So, assuming sensible filename characters and spaces, to work!

First set up your `relative root` (starting subdirectory) name, the filemasks to be used, old and new, and the extension. I've use the `set "var=string"` syntax to avoid application of stray terminal spaces which are invisible and can cause chaos. Note also that in a string assignment, spaces on both sides of the '=' are significant.

First step is as documented. Not sure what to do if there are files matching the new name already in the tree - so do nothing. counting the lines that appear from a `dir /s/b/a-d` (directory, with subdirectories, basic form (so no headers) and no directory names) should be about 0 if all is well.

I like to set up tempfiles using the method showm. If there are no names in `%temp%` matching the random name chosen, then it should be safe to use that name + any appendix you like (so you can create many tempfiles, if required.)

Next step is to get the subdirectory of the old-name files in basic form again - but this time output toa tempfile. What is output is a line for each file, structured as the NAME part only (`%%~ni`) an asterisk and the full filename (`%%~fi`). The asterisk acts as a column-delimiter and is safe because `*` cannot occur in a filename.

Next is the rename phase. We start the `COUNT` at 1000 so that we can use the last 3 characters to create the name. Of you want to start at 001, just use 1001 instead. `PREV` is initialised to a value that can't appear as a filename-to-be-renamed.

Again, count the names to be renamed. If too many, abandon ship.

Next step is to sort the tempfile, so the result will be processed in order of the original base-filename (before the "*" in each line) and then, if the name matches, in alphabetical order of subdirectory name (since name*parent will sort before name*parent\subdir). Each NAME encountered is then passed to the `:incren` routine - quoted to accommodate the spaces-in-filenames requirement.

First thing the INCREN routine does is to check whether the name repeats the previous name encountered. If it does, the name is ignored (as it has already been processed). `PREV` is then set to the next name encountered. `SET "prev=%~1"` removes the quotes from the first parameter, then assigns the result to `prev` and the enclosing quotes prevent stray spaces from butting in. `firstname` and `secondname` are then set to [nothing]

We then scan the tempfile again, looking for a matching name as the first token and assigning the second token (the full-filename) to `%%n`

when the first is found, firstname is not set, so set it to the full-filename.
If a second name is found, then `firstname` will already be set, so set `SKIPPED` to flag that a problem has been encountered. If the second filename has not yet been set, then set `secondname` to *that* full-filename
Should further matches be found, then since `secondname` is now set, nothing further will be done.

After we've processed the file, we will have `firstname` set to the first full-filename (since the relative-root is the first encountered) and `secondname` will only be set if 2 or more matching names were found. In that case, set `firstname` to the value of the second name encountered, which will be in a lower subdirectory.

Now do the RENAME. I've just `ECHO`ed it, but to activate, remove the `ECHO` from the `ECHO REN...` line. We know `firstname` contains the full name of the file to be renamed, and we know the structure of the new filename will be the new mask+the last 3 characters of `COUNT`+a dot+the selected extension.

and bump the count ready for the next rename...

Here's a test run with the `ECHO` removed:

```
============= before =========

u:\photos collection 01\im age 612.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\im age 003.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\im age 005.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\im age 610.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\im age 009.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\im age 609.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\im age 505.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\selection 01\im age 001.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\selection 01\im age 004.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\selection 01\im age 005.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\selection 01\im age 006.jpg

=============  run  =========

some files were NOT renamed
u:\photos collection 01\im age 005.jpg

============= after  =========

u:\photos collection 01\new name009.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\new name001.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\im age 005.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\new name008.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\new name005.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\new name007.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\new name006.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\selection 01\new name000.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\selection 01\new name002.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\selection 01\new name003.jpg
u:\photos collection 01\selection 01\new name004.jpg
```

Note this was executed agains a FAT drive, so the sequence of actual files is the same in the two listings.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this without scripts, if you have Total Commander under Windows (from your path separators in the example, I assume you use Windows).
If you press Ctrl+B, it lists all the files in the current directory and all subdirectories in one lists. Then if you select all of them (*) and press Ctrl+M, the batch rename tool appears and you can rename all of them, set to replace Img with NewName and add a counter to the end of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and remove the `echo`before `move`, if the output is OK:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "sourcefolder=PhotosCollection01"

for /r "%sourcefolder%" %%i in (*.jpg) do (
    if defined "$n%%~nxi" set "$d%%~nxi=%%~nxi"
    set "$p%%~nxi=%%~dpi"
    set "$n%%~nxi=%%~nxi"
)
set "$d" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo(Duplicate filename(s^):
    for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%i in ('set $d') do echo(%%i
    goto:eof
)
set /a counter=1000
for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%i in ('set $n') do (
    set /a counter+=1
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if exist "!$p%%~i!NewName!counter:~-3!%%~xi" (
    echo(file already exists: "!$p%%~i!NewName!counter:~-3!%%~xi"
    ) else echo move "!$p%%~i!%%~i" "!$p%%~i!NewName!counter:~-3!%%~xi"
    endlocal
)
```

The script terminates, if duplicate filenames are found in the subfolders.
If the targetfile already exists, it will not be overwritten. Please note: all folders in %sourcefolder% use the same counter. If you have different selections, call this script for each or write a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting topic! I understand your request this way: 1- Create a list of unique file names from PhotosCollection and Chosen, but give priority to Chosen's files (PhotosCollection's files with same name will be removed). 2- Rename the files in the list with consecutive numbers starting from 001. The Batch file below achieve this process, but it process *all* directories in current directory (from PhotosCollection01 to PhotosCollectionNN) and process this way *all* the subdirectories under each directory, that is, if Chosen subdirectory have "brothers", they all are processed in the same way.

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Set this value as you wish (ie: set NewName=New Name With Spaces)
set NewName=NewName

rem Process all directories at this level
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   rem Enter into this directory (ie: PhotosCollection01)
   cd "%%a"
   rem Insert file names in the initial list as "parent" (ie: Img003.jpg Img004.jpg Img005.jpg)
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   for %%c in (*.jpg) do (
      set unique[%%c]=.
   )
   rem Process each subdirectory
   for /D %%b in (*) do (
      rem Enter into this subdirectory (ie: Chosen)
      cd "%%b"
      rem Process "nested" file names (ie: Img005.jpg Img010.jpg)
      for %%c in (*.jpg) do (
         if "!unique[%%c]!" equ "." (
            rem Delete duplicated file in parent directory (ie: PhotosCollection01\Img005.jpg)
            del "..\%%c"
         )
         rem Insert file name in the list as "nested"
         set unique[%%c]=%%b
      )
      rem Go back to parent directory (ie: PhotosCollection01)
      cd ..
   )
   rem Rename all names in the list from 001 and up
   set number=1000
   for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%c in ('set unique[') do (
      set /A number+=1
      ren "%%d\%%c" "%NewName%!number:~-3!.jpg"
   )
   rem Delete the list
   endlocal
   rem Go back to original directory (where PhotosColection01...NN exist)
   cd ..
)
```

Put this Batch file in the same folder that contain the Collections and execute it, you must do that with test files a couple times until you are satisfied with the result. Note that the method may be easily modified in order to also delete or rename duplicated files in all Chosen's brothers folders, that is, if "Chosen2" folder have Img010.jpg file (that is also in Chosen), delete or rename Chosen's or Chosen2's one (currently they are preserved, but not renamed). All directory and file names may have spaces, but names that include exclamation marks will not be correctly processed; this detail may be fixed, if needed.

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test
>dir /b
PhotosCollection01
renumber.bat

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test
>dir /b PhotosCollection01
Chosen
Img003.jpg
Img004.jpg
Img005.jpg
Img007.jpg
Img010.jpg

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test
>dir /b PhotosCollection01\Chosen
Img005.jpg
Img010.jpg

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test
>renumber.bat

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test
>dir /b PhotosCollection01
Chosen
NewName001.jpg
NewName002.jpg
NewName004.jpg

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test
>dir /b PhotosCollection01\Chosen
NewName003.jpg
NewName005.jpg
```